# facebook like button on every element of gridview

Tags: facebook-like, blogs

i have a gridview displaying articles and for every article i,e for every row of a grid i want to put face book like button. how can i achieve this...

In itemtemplate of my grid i have placed the below script:
   
                        
                                                    (function (d, s, id) {
                                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id))
                                    return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
                                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                                             ' data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false">

but, it is working for few articles only,if you like for few in my facebook profile page i am getting muliple likes of one article instead of only one like. this is my major problem pls give me solution to this. Thanks